# Meteor JS render and DOM update

Tags: javascript, meteor

Im brand new to MeteorJS and I just can't seem to wrap my head around it.  Or come away from thinking in Jquery.

But anyways.

I have a game collection, which lists a bunch of games, which is fine.

Inside the game collection i have an array of 10 cells

```
  cells = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
```

Im rendering the cells in a template

```
  <template name='cells'>
    {{#each cells}}
       <span class='cell'>{{this}}</span> -
    {{/each}}
  </template>
```

This renders as expected

```
   0 - 0 - 0 - 0 - 0 - 0 - 0 - 0 - 0 - 0
```

However....
I now want to be able to have a user click on the cells and change the value to a 2.

I know how to do this using a template helper, and some jQuery for class Updating.

But how do I get it to actually reflect on the server / another page???

I have this...

```
  Template.cell.events({
    'click .cell':function(evt, template){
         //Update the cell in the game collection.
         //  So [0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0] for example.
        $(evt.currentTarget).addClass('newUpdate').html(2);

    };
  });
```

But I want this to be live.  So that when one person changes it, the class gets applied and the html and colour gets updated on all pages apart from the one Im dealing with.

Like how do I change the model directly, and have the dom automatically apply the appropriate classes and what not, across all clients??

Answer (score 0):

You should update your collection on click event.
Like this

```
MyCollection.update({_id:idOfYourcollection}:{$set:{nameOfFieldtochance: newvalue}})
```

magic and your application is now live.